# Some mangled Swift symbols can't be de-mangled

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, plcrashreporter

I'm trying to de-mangle mangled Swift symbols with `swift-demangle`. Some symbols are de-mangled just fine, but some others can't be de-mangled at all no matter what verison of Swift I'm using. Example: I've tried to de-mangle `_TTSf4g_n_n_n___TTOFE5UIKitCSo18NSAttributedStringcfzT4dataV10Foundation4Data7optionsGVs10DictionarySSP__18documentAttributesGSqGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo12NSDictionary____S0_` using the `swift-demangle` utility from the following Swift versions: `2.2.1`, `3.0.1`, `3.0.2`, `3.1`, `3.1.1`, `4.0.2`, `4.0.3` and `4.1`, using the following command:

```
swift-demangle -compact -no-sugar -simplified _TTSf4g_n_n_n___TTOFE5UIKitCSo18NSAttributedStringcfzT4dataV10Foundation4Data7optionsGVs10DictionarySSP__18documentAttributesGSqGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo12NSDictionary____S0_
```

, but all resulted in the same mangled symbol as the input.

I'm currently compiling Swift `2.2.1` to see whether the symbol can be de-mangled there (which I doubt)... Any advice on what possibly could be the reason behind those symbols not being able to be de-mangled would be really appreciated...

Comment: I'm still puzzling through why it doesn't demangle, but this is definitely `NSAttributedString.init(data:options:documentAttributes:)`.